# How to browse through a BPMN diagram using Java

Tags: bpmn

I'm wondering how to browse a BPMN diagram using eclipse. I'm looking for a means to help me. Any help please. I'm really lost.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Activiti - they have instructions on how to in their [User Guide](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#eclipseDesignerInstallation).

TL;DR: Add New Software (URL = http://activiti.org/designer/update/)